# Is there a way to fix this end effect of plotting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

[image]

```
 WaterFraction=[0.705 0.047 -0.15 -0.046 0.18 -0.070 -0.089 -0.0815 -0.0731 -0.08 ...
                   -0.43 -0.537 -0.543 -0.62 -0.548 -0.55 -0.33 -0.112 0.10 0.0590 ]
Radius=[ -1.25 -0.811 -0.448 -0.320 -0.384  -0.0923 0.168   0.1039 0.039 0.276 ...
        -0.127 -0.137 -0.1088 -0.080 0.0220 0.049 2.34 4.58 6.84 -8.0]
```

When I plot a data vector by its time vector, and both are the same size of course, this happens sometimes and it is visually displeasing.

I am referring to the straight lines from the end that come back to the origin.
Best,
Abid

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you're plotting? The first and last 10 `[t,x]` values should do it.

Comment: And what `plot` command are you using?

Comment: I am using the plotyy command

Answer (score 3):

You've got a couple of options, depending on your circumstances.  You can either sort the data to prevent the discontinuities, or you can insert a few `NaN`s into the X and Y vectors.

1. To sort:

   ```
   [xSorted, ixsSort] = sort(x);
   ySorted = y(ixSort);
   plot(xSorted, ySorted);
   ```
2. To add nans, you need to do some additional work to determine where the breaks should be, and then insert NaNs.  For example, to break the line after the 10th entry

   ```
   xBroken = [x(1:10) nan x(11:end)];
   yBroken = [y(1:10) nan y(11:end)];
   plot(xBroken, yBroken);
   ```

   Edit:  see sample code below for a more comprehensive example.
3. Of course, as an easy backup, just do a scatter plot instead of a line plot:

   ```
   plot(x, y, '.');
   ```

---

Some sample code for method 2 below:

```
%Some sample data
x = [1:10 2.1:11 3.2:12];
y = randn(size(x));

%Define where breaks are needed (and associated boundaries)
ixsBreaksNeeded = find(diff(x)<0);
ixsSegmentBoundaries = [0 ixsBreaksNeeded length(x)];  %This makes the iterations a lot easier

%Predefine some nan vectors to move data into
xBroken = nan(1, length(x) + length(ixsBreaksNeeded));
yBroken = nan(1, length(x) + length(ixsBreaksNeeded));

%Move data segments into nan vectors, leaving gaps between segments
ixOffset = 0;
for ix = 2:length(ixsSegmentBoundaries)
    ixsOriginal = (ixsSegmentBoundaries(ix-1)+1):ixsSegmentBoundaries(ix);
    xBroken(ixsOriginal + (ixOffset)) = x(ixsOriginal);
    yBroken(ixsOriginal + (ixOffset)) = y(ixsOriginal);
    ixOffset = ixOffset+1;
end

%Plot to demonstrate
subplot(211)
plot(x,y);
subplot(212)
plot(xBroken, yBroken)
```

Comment: These are very good suggestions, the 1st and 3rd of which I have tried and do not work for my data due to it being a time series and also because it is sampled so that it is not clear when scattered. I also dont understand what you mean by your 2nd suggestion.

Comment: For approach 2, to find the points in your time series where the time jumps backwards, use `find(diff(t) < 0)' and instert NaNs at these locations